# Combining column name is causing error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have two columns which I want to combine and show the data, I tried like below

```
select 
    case 
       when status = 'R' 
          then 'Resign'
       when status = 'A' 
          then 'Active' 
    end as status1, 
    Program_name + ' ' + emp_card_no as program_details,
    * 
from 
    GetEmployeeDetails
where 
    emp_name = 'ABHAY ASHOK MANE'
    and STATUS = 'A' 
order by
    EMP_NAME
```

but I am getting an error:

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Here is the sample data available

[image: img]

Comment: i suppose emp_car_no is an integer field ? Is so than use this : Program_name + ' ' + convert(varchar, emp_car_no)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
select 
  case when status='R' then 'Resign'
       when status='A' then 'Active' 
  end as status1, 
  Program_name + ' (' + convert(varchar, emp_card_no) + ') ' as program_details,
* 
from GetEmployeeDetails
Where emp_name ='ABHAY ASHOK MANE'and STATUS= 'A' ORDER BY EMP_NAME
```

Comment: yes it's coming, I just want to display it as Saiwadi (2552). then ? I mean, I want bracket for card no

Comment: @stack I have edited my answer so the card no is beween brackets

Answer (score 2):

If you need parentheses, use following:

```
select 
  case when status='R' then 'Resign'
       when status='A' then 'Active' 
  end as status1, 
  Program_name + ' (' + convert(varchar(10), emp_card_no)+')' as program_details,
* 
from GetEmployeeDetails
Where emp_name ='ABHAY ASHOK MANE'and STATUS= 'A' ORDER BY EMP_NAME
```

Comment: one more thing, I want to show `Program_id` in place of emp_card_no then how to get that ?

Comment: If Program_id is not VARCHAR just replace emp_card_no and if VARCHAR no need to casting and also replace with emp_card_no

Answer (score 2):

**CAST** Int value column to VARCHAR:

In your query **cast emp_card_no** to VARCHAR

```
select 
    case when status='R' then 'Resign'
    when status='A' then 'Active' end as status1, 
    [Program_name] + ' ' + CAST(emp_card_no AS VARCHAR(50)) as program_details,
* 
from GetEmployeeDetails
Where emp_name ='ABHAY ASHOK MANE'and STATUS= 'A' ORDER BY EMP_NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use concat which will convert internally..

```
select case when status='R' then 'Resign'
when status='A' then 'Active' end as status1, 
 concat(Program_name, ' ', emp_card_no) as program_details,
* from GetEmployeeDetails
Where emp_name ='ABHAY ASHOK MANE'and STATUS= 'A' ORDER BY EMP_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

column combination can be done for string type values. so you have to convert columns into varchar data type if not.

Below is your solution with **one improvement in case statement.**

```
select 
case status 
   when 'R' 
      then 'Resign'
   when 'A' 
      then 'Active' 
end as status1, 
Program_name + ' ' + convert(varchar(50),emp_card_no) as program_details,
* 
from 
GetEmployeeDetails
where 
emp_name = 'ABHAY ASHOK MANE'
and STATUS = 'A' 
order by
EMP_NAME
```